# how to add/remove composite field in extjs 3.4 dynamically

Tags: extjs3

i am using extjs 3.4 add add this code for add /remove key value pair in field set but is not working fine it is add the field dynamically but when we remove this browser given the infinite loop error and after some time field is also given the following error:

TypeError: this.dom is undefined
here is my code :

//This js for test only

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    function addressCounter(incr) {
        if (!this.no) {
            this.no = 0;
        } else {
            this.no = this.no + 1;
        };
    };
    var counter = new addressCounter();
    console.log(counter.no);
    var roomPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
       renderTo:"sid",
        id: "roomFP",
        baseCls: 'x-plain',
        labelWidth: 120,
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        monitorValid:true,
        bodyStyle: ' padding: 15px; background-color: #ffffff' ,
        items:[
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Room Properties',
            collapsible: true,
            id:'roompropertiesId',
            items:[new Ext.Button({
                text:'Add Property',
                handler: function(item){
                    var fieldset  = Ext.getCmp('roompropertiesId');
                    if(fieldset.items.length >5){
                        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Add Property','only five fields has been added');
                        return;
                    } 
                    counter.no = counter.no + 1;
                    var a = fieldset.add({
                        xtype            : 'compositefield'
                        ,
                        id                : 'compositefieldId'+counter.no
                        ,
                        name                : 'name'+counter.no
                        ,
                        height            : 22
                        ,
                        autoDestroy    : true
                        ,
                        items            : [{
                            name        : 'key'+counter.no
                            ,
                            fieldLabel    : "Key",
                            id                : 'keyFieldId'+counter.no
                            ,
                            xtype        : 'textfield'
                            ,
                            width        : 50
                            ,
                            height        : 22
                            ,
                            allowBlank    : true
                        },{
                            name        : 'value'+counter.no
                            ,
                            xtype        : 'textfield',
                            id           : 'valueFieldId'+counter.no
                            ,
                            fieldLabel    : 'Value'
                            ,
                            width        : 50
                            ,
                            allowBlank    : true
                        },{
                            xtype    : 'displayfield',
                            id:'removeFieldId'+counter.no,
                            html    : '<div class="img-delete" onclick="removeFormFields(\''+counter.no+'\');"><a href="#">Remove</a></div>'
                            ,
                            height    : 16
                        }]
                    });
                    fieldset.doLayout();
                    removeFormFields = function(id) {
                        Ext.getCmp('compositefieldId'+id).destroy();
                    }
                }
            })]
        }
        ],
        listeners : {
            render : function(form){
            }
        },
       });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is bug in Ext JS.
When you put normal `Container` instead of `CompositeField` then it works properly.
I figured out that `CompositeField` subfields are added to `BasicForm` (`FormPanel.getForm`) on `CompositeField` creation, but aren't removed. This causes that, for example, `BasicForm` validation refers to destroyed fields, and causes error.
IMO you can freely switch from `CompositeField` to `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

Call formPanel.getForm().cleanDestroyed() after composite component is destroyed.